# How to reduce NSTimeInterval every time the score is increased by 5

Tags: ios, swift, nstimeinterval

I have a variable called duration which is a NSTimeInterval(3). 3 is the number of objects on the screen and the new object begin to fall when the last is at the bottom of the screen. I want this number reduce, because it will fall faster when there will be less objects. I want it reduce every time the score is increased by 5 from last reduce. But if I write there this code it does nothing:

```
if ((self.score % 5) == 0) {
    self.duration--
}
```

How can I do it?

Thanks

Comment: How do you use `self.duration` to affect the game?

Comment: @MartinMikusovic: Please edit your question and add all relevant information to the question itself.

Comment: Do you mean `NSTimeInterval(self.duration)`? Better yet, please edit your question to include the code that uses duration.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the "Swifty" answer would be something like this:

```
var score:Int {
     didSet {
         self.duration--
     }
}
```

That said you haven't really given enough info to say why `self.duration--` would not work, so I'm assuming that code just isn't being called.